# Bluetooth not working on my HP Compaq 8200 Elite Tower

Tags: bluetooth, hp, compaq

I have problém with installing bluetooth driver for HP Compaq 8200 Elite. I tried some drivers, during installation seemes ok but bluetooth not working. Can you help me? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Why are you trying "some drivers"? What is the BT device? The specs don't say there is a built-in BT device.

Comment: I tried some because there were no drivers to be found for it and I wanted to try at least anything, stupid I know that now. I have Chipset Intel Q67 Express, it is this machine exactly:  https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-compaq-8200-elite-microtower-pc/5037940/document/c02779504#AbT0

Comment: I tried it only with sudo apt-get install and from hp official pages.

Comment: So there is no BT.